# Screenpad (Asus Zenbook's screen touchpad) gestures on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: touchpad, asus, synaptics, 20.10

I want to enable some gestures to my Screenpad (Asus Zenbook's screen touchpad). I got an Asus UX334F and using Ubuntu 20.10.

Some nice gestures could be pinch-to-zoom on the browser (google chrome) or 2-finger-backward, like MacOS systems, and since this is not a synaptics touchpad I'm asking this question as it has different drivers.

As it is a screen, if it helps - ubuntu recognizes it like Toshiba America Info Systems Inc 6".

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at:

- X11 Gesture [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4033/x11-gestures/)
- Touchegg [here](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg)

The experience is not the same as on MacOS, though.